# Mapper Mapper|User|users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'users'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

########################################################################
class User(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "users"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
username = Column(String)
password = Column(String)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, username, password):
    """"""
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

# create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This is supposed to create a db structure with the file name **database.db** but the error pops out and how do i solve it ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your indentation is as you've presented here, then you have a simple typo. The columns and the `__init__` function are not a part of your class' body.

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an indentation Issue.
Solved it.
Solution:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

########################################################################
class User(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, username, password):
    """"""
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

# create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I received this error because I wrote it like

```
Column('id', Integer)
Column('username', String)
```

Vs

```
id = Column('id', Integer)
username = Column('username', String)
```